# Angular 13 Prerender error could not find main bundle

Tags: angular, typescript, build, prerender

I'm trying to pre-render my Angular 13 application. The command which I'm running is:

```
ng run ipe:prerender --routes-file ./data/routes.txt
```

The error that occurring is:

```
    An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the main bundle: /Users/username/projects/ipe/dist/ipe/server/main.js
    See "/private/var/folders/wh/nz9_hkk52hxc87vcv53tmhj40000gn/T/ng-ygeQrx/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The individual build and server builds in the architect run fine without error.

```
ng run ipe:build
ng run ipe:server
```

The code can be found here.

https://github.com/ng-druid/ipe

Comment: Not sure how prerender works exactly but it can't find the main.js from angular universal so you might wanna build that first and see if that solves the issue. e.g. `npm run build:ssr`.

Comment: When I run `ng run ipe:build && ng run ipe:server` the main file exists where it should. However, when I run `ng run ipe:prerender` the directory is cleared and the server directory is never regenerated. Although the prerender build schedules both the browser and server builds. It doesn't look like the server build is working inside the the prerender build. That is as much as I can make out up til now.

Comment: I'm not sure but I vaguely recall prerender not being available in angular universal projects, I'm not sure though. Could be some weird error, try running with `--verbose` to see if any other logs pop up.

Comment: When I added verbose true to the build options for the server in the architect json it worked.

Comment: However, I ran it again after wards and it didn't work again. Same error as before.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I might have found an answer to this. When I clear the cache in angular cli the problem goes away. I think this might have something to do with the cache thinking the server build is available but it is not since each time the build runs it is erased.

```
rm -rf .angular/cache
```

Also I'm not having this problem at all on my other project. I copied the boilerplate to this one and it doesn't work the same. There must be something in the configuration I'm missing that is slightly different between the two.

Answer (score 0):

This issue still persisted time to time until the server build was moved outside the client build. Once the server build was moved to a dedicated folder outside the client build the problem seems to have went away.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).